# DataTable deserialization suddenly gives error in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, serialization, datatable

I have an application that passes information from and to a server. I created a binary serializable Message object with the following serialization methods:

```
''' <summary>
''' this method is used for serlization
''' </summary>
Public Sub GetObjectData(ByVal info As System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, ByVal context As System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext) Implements System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.GetObjectData
info.AddValue("message", Message, Message.GetType)
info.AddValue("tp", OBJ.GetType.ToString, Message.GetType)
info.AddValue("object", OBJ, OBJ.GetType)
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' deserialization
''' </summary>
Public Sub New(ByVal info As System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, ByVal context As System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)
Message = info.GetString("message")
Dim TP As String = info.GetString("tp")
OBJ = info.GetValue("object", Type.GetType(TP))
End Sub
```

Usually I fill Message with the name or note about the object i am passing, and OBJ with the object itself. The code was working until few hours ago.

I did many changes which included removing some of the application settings, but never modified the serialization. After that the deserialization started to fail when the OBJ member variable has a datatable in it.

I have been searching the net for a similar error, but couldn't find any.

The exception I am getting when deserializing the datatable is:

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

and the stack is:

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._SerializationInvoke(Object target, SignatureStruct& declaringTypeSig, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.SerializationInvoke(Object target, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
>      at IDMS.IDMS_Message.DeSerializeObject(Byte[] B) in E:\my project AMS\Modules\Utilities\IDMS_Message.vb:line 60

Is there a setting that controls binary serialization for a datatable? Could the error has something to do with the network? if so, why serialization/deserialization for a list of objects still works perfectly fine, but the datatable serlization gives an error?

And why this error appeared suddenly?

Any advice is highly appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Objects cannot be serialized, instead serialize the contents (or props of it depending on what it is). I cant tell if it is the DT or your OBJ that is the cause from that little bit of code. You can do your own serialization or write some type converter code maybe.  Finally I am not sure what you are passing this **to** but the NET BF can only deserialize into the same assembly-class-culture type without some reflection gyration to basically.  Trick it.  Look at ProtoBuf-NET instead (faster, smaller than BF).

Comment: Hi there... Thanks for the reply. I solved the issue, it turned out that the Type.GetType("System.Data.DataTable") returns nothing instead of a data type which is the actual reason. Also, I removed all the user settings files that the application generates, and the code works perfectly as before. I think the setting issue was the reason.

Comment: Few minutes ago, some clients had the same issue. Even after removing the settings files, the error was still there. Finally we had to perform an installation to fix the issue.